# Propagate exception message from service to controller .NET

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, amazon-dynamodb

I have a .NET appplication where there is a controller for receiving user requests, a service `Service 1` which calls another service `Service 2`.
I have some code in the `Service 2` where I query the database(DynamoDB) and get a 500 error in response when the user request values are incorrect. I want to handle this such that I catch this error/exception and send back the error message along with a 400 status code from the controller to the user. How should I modify the code to do this?

This is what I have tried. Currently, I'm just printing the error in `Service 1` but I need to send it to the controller. Is sending the error message to the controller by throwing exceptions along the way the right way to do it?

The below code is similar to the actual code

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Policy = "Read-Entity")]
    [Route("byParams/{param1}/{param2}")]
    [Produces(typeof(DynamoResult<EntityResponse>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListByParams([FromQuery] DynamoQuery entityQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            return await HandleRequest(async () =>
            {
                return Ok((await _entityStore.ListByParams(entityQuery)));
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Service 1:**

```
public async Task<DynamoResult<EntityResponse>> ListByParams(DynamoQuery entityQuery)
{            
    results = new DynamoResult<Entity>();
    try {
        results = await GetPagedQueryResults(entityQuery);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e);             
    }
    return new DynamoResult<EntityResponse>
    {
        Data = results.Data.Select(_mapper.Map<EntityResponse>).ToList(),                
    };        
}
```

**Service 2:**

```
private async Task<DynamoResult<TResponse>> GetPagedQueryResults(DynamoQuery query)
{
    var results = new List<Document>();
    try{
        results = await search.GetNextSetAsync();
    }        
    catch(Exception e){
        throw new PaginationTokenException(e.Message);
    }
    return results;
}

[Serializable]
public class PaginationTokenException : Exception
{
    public PaginationTokenException() { }

    public PaginationTokenException(string message)
        : base(message) { 
            throw new Exception(message);
        }

    public PaginationTokenException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to hide implementation details from the controller (i.e. you don't want the controller to know/care that it's DynamoDB), I would create a custom exception and throw that from `Service1`.

Service1 would look something like this:

```cs
public async Task<DynamoResult<EntityResponse>> ListByParams(DynamoQuery entityQuery)
{            
    results = new DynamoResult<Entity>();
    try {
        results = await GetPagedQueryResults(entityQuery);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyCustomException('My error message', e);             
    }
    return new DynamoResult<EntityResponse>
    {
        Data = results.Data.Select(_mapper.Map<EntityResponse>).ToList(),                
    };        
}
```

In the controller you can then capture that exception explicitly:

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Policy = "Read-Entity")]
    [Route("byParams/{param1}/{param2}")]
    [Produces(typeof(DynamoResult<EntityResponse>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListByParams([FromQuery] DynamoQuery entityQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            return await HandleRequest(async () =>
            {
                return Ok((await _entityStore.ListByParams(entityQuery)));
            });
        }
        catch (MyCustomException e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well I implemented your solution and the control reaches the `throw` statement of the catch block in `Service 1` but I again get the same 500 response. I don't think the exception is travelling to the Controller. How would you implement the constructor of `MyCustomException`? Do I need to add anything to  the constructor in `PaginationTokenException` exception handler that I'm using?

Comment: You have explicitly checked that you reached the catch block in your Controller or not?

Comment: @Ralf I have checked that. It does not reach the catch block in the controller.

Comment: Then we can speculate that the HandleRequest method catches the exception and returns something instead of propagating the exception. You might look into HandleRequest or put the exceptionhandling into the delegate given to HandleRequest instead of surrounding that call.